# Google penalty recovery

Tags: backlinks

I have a site, which is a spiritual site and has nothing to do with commercial or business thing.

It was in the first page with the keyword `RADHANATH SWAMI`. Then suddenly, in sep'13, the site went out from google search. When I checked my WebmasterTools, I saw that there were 40,000 backlinks from a site named http://freeguestbooks.net.
But manual action section in WebmasterToolssaid "No Manual webspam actions found" and till date, it shows the same.

Then I contacted the webmaster of freeguestbooks.net and requested him to remove the 40K odd backlinks and he very kindly removed it. The WebmasterTools now shows 21,777 backlinks from this site. But since 2 months, the decrease rate of these backlinks is very slow, almost zero. Again, I had contacted the webmaster of freeguestbooks.net and he confirmed that there are no backlinks pointing to his site.
I am also told that my anchor text is over-optimised...

Total backlinks to my site as per WebmasterTools is only 24,937 out of which 21,777 are the links from freeguestbooks.net as shown in WebmasterTools.

Can you suggest a way out to get back into google?

Comment: You can disavow the links in Google Webmaster Tools, but with so many, that is not practical. You can also asked to be reconsidered (not sure where this is done). The thing is, your situation is not unique. I have seen this here before. Outside of that, you may have no option but to wait. Just some thoughts while you wait for a better answer.

Comment: When you disavowed the links, did you do it link by link or disavow the entire freeguestbooks.net domain?

Comment: Do you Allow Comments?  Have a look at the [Akismet Plugin](http://akismet.com/)

Comment: @JCL1178 I just requested the webmaster of freeguestbooks to remove the links and he kindly removed them. If i check the links of freeguestbooks in my GWMT, then it is no more valid, but are still being shown there...

Comment: I think you need to use the Disavow Links tool and nuke them.  Clearly, the owner of freeguestbooks.net hasn't fully removed the links or (as @closetnoc said) you haven't let enough time pass for Google to note the changes.  But I would not leave this to the other site to do...your site is your business and you need to take the steps to protect it.

Comment: JCL, I hv already done the disavow in oct'13. In GWMT, only 139 links are shown of freeguestbooks.net which i hv seen all are dead...it's 8 months now...

Comment: I don't think we will be able to help you with this issue.   There are many algorithm updates from Google that could cause your site to drop and we have no way of knowing which one was the one that caused your problem.